# How can I ensure a child process eventually writes data in C?

Tags: c, exec, pipe

In C, I'd like to fork off a child process, and map its STDIN and STDOUT to pipes. The parent then communicates with the child by writing to or reading from the child's STDIN and STDOUT.

The MWE code below is apparently successful. The parent thread receives the string "Sending some message", and I can send arbitrary messages to the parent thread by writing to stdout. I can also freely read messages from the parent using, e.g. scanf.

The problem is that, once execl is called by the child, the output seems to stop coming through. I know that without the call to setvbuf to unbuffer stdout, this code will hang indefinitely, and so I suppose that the call to execl re-buffers stdout. Since the child program ./a.out is itself interactive, we hit a race condition where the child will not write (because of the buffering), and blocks waiting for input, while the parent blocks waiting for the child to write before producing input for the child.

Is there a nice way to avoid this? In particular, is there a way to use exec that doesn't overwrite the attributes of stdin stdout, etc.?

```
int main(char* argv[], int argc){
        int mgame_read_pipe[2];
        int mgame_write_pipe[2];
        pipe(mgame_read_pipe);
        pipe(mgame_write_pipe);
        pid_t is_child = fork();
        if(is_child == -1){
                perror("Error while forking.");
                exit(1);
        }
        if(is_child==0){
                dup2(mgame_read_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                printf("Sending some message.\n");
                dup2(mgame_write_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
                setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
                close(mgame_read_pipe[0]);
                close(mgame_write_pipe[1]);
                execl("./a.out", "./a.out", NULL);
        }
        else{
                close(mgame_read_pipe[1]);
                close(mgame_write_pipe[0]);

                int status;
                do{
                        printf("SYSTEM: Waiting for inferior process op.\n");
                        char buf[BUFSIZ];
                        read(mgame_read_pipe[0], buf, BUFSIZ);
                        printf("%s",buf);
                        scanf("%s", buf);
                        printf("SYSTEM: Waiting for inferior process ip.\n");
                        write(mgame_write_pipe[1], buf, strlen(buf));
                } while( !waitpid(is_child, &status, WNOHANG) );
        }
}
```

EDIT: For completeness, here's an (untested) example a.out:

```
int main(){
    printf("I'm alive!");
    int parent_msg;
    scanf("%d", &parent_msg);
    printf("I got %d\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that ./a.out's STDIN is mapped to the read end of mgame_write_pipe. So it's actually waiting for input from the parent in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buffering problems stem from the fact that the buffering is being performed by the C standard library in the program that you are exec-ing, not at the kernel / file descriptor level (as observed by @Claris). There is nothing you can do to affect buffering in another programs own code (unless you modify that program).

This is actually a common problem encountered by anyone trying to automate interaction with a program.

One solution is to use a pseudo-tty, which makes the program think it is actually talking to an interactive terminal, which alters it's buffering behaviour, amongst other things.

[This article](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html) provides a good introduction. There is an example program there showing exactly how to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: That article looks like exactly what's needed.

Comment: Indeed, the example that is shown works perfectly for my application with only minor tweaks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The setvbuf options you are setting have to do with stdio streams and not file descriptors so will have no effect.

The read/write system calls are not buffered (aside from caching which is different and which might exist in the kernel), so you don't need to worry about disabling a buffer or any other such stuff. They will go directly to where they need to go.

That being said, they are blocking so if the kernel does not have enough data to fill your IO block size they will block at the OS level until that data exists and can be copied to/from your buffer. They will only provide you less than the data you asked for if an EOF condition is encountered or you have enabled async/non blocking IO.

You may be able to enable non-blocking IO through a system call using the fcntl interface. This would return immediately but is not always supported depending on how you are using a file descriptor. Async IO (for files) is supported through the AIO interface.